# Mysql compare two group_concat results against each other

Tags: php, mysql, compare, group-concat, having

I have a table `events` and a table `invoices`

Each `event` can have up to 5 `invoices` (invoices have an event_id, and can only have one event)

Each invoice has two fields, "cancelled" and "paperwork_received_datestamp".  We consider a "fully completed event" as each non-cancelled invoice having a date entered for that field. I need to show a list of only "fully completed events".

I have this query

```
SELECT
     Event.id, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(Invoice.cancelled) AS "cancelled_status",
     GROUP_CONCAT(IF(Invoice.paperwork_received_datestamp IS NOT NULL, "installed", "not_installed")) AS "paperwork_status"
FROM
     `events` `Event`
     LEFT JOIN invoices Invoice ON Invoice.event_id = Event.id
WHERE
     YEAR(Invoice.submit_date) = 2015
GROUP BY
     Event.id
```

This productes an output such as

```
Event ID ---- cancelled_status---- paperwork_status

 23562 --------no,no,no ------------installed,installed,installed (this row should show up)

 21563 -------no,no,yes -------------installed,installed,not_installed (this row should show up)

 24672 --------no,no ----------------installed,not_installed (this row shouldn't show up)

25784 ----------yes,yes -------------not_installed,not_installed (this row shouldn't show up)
```

The only way I can think to do this would be to use explode on both group_concat fields in PHP and loop through each row and use some logic and exclude the rows I want to exclude to create the list.  I'd rather do it in mySQL.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I figured an answer.  (I'm open to better ways of doing it though)

```
SELECT
     GROUP_CONCAT(IF(Invoice.cancelled = "NO" && Invoice.paperwork_received_datestamp IS NULL, "incomplete", "complete")) AS "test"
FROM
     `events` `Event`
      LEFT JOIN invoices Invoice ON Invoice.event_id = Event.id
WHERE
      YEAR(Invoice.submit_date) = 2015
GROUP BY
      Event.id
 HAVING 
      INSTR(test, 'i') = 0 /* removes all incompletes */
```